# React-intl: Why need to define Messages using either <FormattedMessage> Component or defineMessagesAPI function

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

I currently have the translated English and Japanese .json file in the format:

```
{
"en": [{
    "id": "Cancel",
    "defaultMessage": "Cancel"
}, {
    "id": "CommonTags",
    "defaultMessage": "Common Tags"
}]
"ja": [{
    "id": "Cancel",
    "defaultMessage": "キャンセル"
}, {
    "id": "CommonTags",
    "defaultMessage": "共通タグ"
    }]}
```

My question is, why do I need to define the messages now considering that I already have all of these generated and translated? I am simply like to access them in the following way but getting an error:

```
var messages_ja = require("../../../Resources/Resources.ja2.js.json");

class LocalizedApp extends React.Component {
props: any;
static propTypes: { intl: (object: any, key: string, componentName: string, ...rest: any[]) => Error | null; };
render() {
    return (...
       <h1>{this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: messages_ja.Cancel })}</h1>);}}
```

I get the following error:

[React Intl] An `id` must be provided to format a message.

Repeating my question:

1. Do I really need to incorporate the ecosystem for defining messages.
   If so, why?
2. Is it possible to simply access the strings based on
       locale from the json, without creating formattedMessages for them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for question 1:**

I'd say yes. You have to choose between using the declarative (e.g.: `<FormattedMessage />`) or the imperative api (e.g.: `intl.formatMessage()`).

**Answer for question 2:**

You could, but then why would you use `react-intl` then?
 (You could say that you only want to use its localization methods for date, numbers, percentage.. which would be ok, but IMHO you'd have much more effort to build your own solution other than using the lib.)

I always prefer to use the declarative API, and it's a good practice to have an *ID* and a *default message*. This default message that react-intl complains is actually to help you. It's a fallback for in case you missed one translation, it defaults to this message.

I recommend using the imperative api if you want to reuse labels or if you need to use them outside react components (from my experience, these were the only cases where it could be done). You can also use the [babel-plugin-react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/babel-plugin-react-intl) to auto-extract the labels from your application and make your life pretty much easy!